# Using cut command

Tags: terminal, grep, cut

Let's say that I have this file (a file named file_1) that contains:

```
{
   "a":100,
   "b":2045,
}
```

How can I keep only the number 100?

I have tried the command (grep "a" | cut -d ':' -f 2)

But I want only the 100. How can I do that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: grep "a" | cut -d ':' -f 2|sed -e "s/,/ /g"

Answer (score 4):

Your command results in `100,`. What you need is simply one more step. There are several alternatives:

- another cut, with field delimiter `,`, select the first field:
  `grep "a" | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ',' -f 1`
- you could also remove (i.e. replace with nothing) the comma with sed: 
  `grep "a" | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sed "s/,//g"`
- speaking of sed: sed can rewrite the answer into the desired form, too:
  `grep "a" | sed -E "s/.*:(.*),/\1/g"`

  - here we substitute something that consists of

    1. a part before `:`
    2. a part between `:` and `,`  in parentheses
  - with `\1`: that is the part of the search matched inside the parentheses, here the number between `:` and `,`
- it gets even easier with sed alone, since sed can also do greps task:
  `sed -E -n '/"a":/ {s/.*:(.*),/\1/g; p }'`

  - the `/"a:"/` defines a match and the following part in braces defines what should be done when the line matches, here the rewriting, as explained above, then print the rewritten line with`p`.